# Why can't a react stateless function return an array?

Tags: reactjs

Here's my stateless function that tries to return an array of elements:

```
function DeliveryPreference (props) {
  return [
      <h4>
        Delivery Preference
        </h4>,
        <div className='yesNoCheckbox'>
          <input type="radio" value={'tube'} onChange={props.onChange} id='tube' checked={props.value === 'tube'}/> <label htmlFor='tube'>Tube</label> <br/>
          <input type="radio" value={'plate'} onChange={props.onChange} id='plate' checked={props.value === 'plate'}/> <label htmlFor='plate'>Plate</label><br/>
        </div>
  ];
}
```

Can anyone explain why I can't do that, and/or provide a work-around?

Thanks very much!

Edit: 
Here's a minimal example of the error:

```
function App (props) {
    return [
    <div>1</div>,
    <div>2</div>,
    ]
}


ReactDOM.render( 
    <App/>
    , document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: can you see any errors?

Comment: yes: Warning: DeliveryPreference(...): No `render` method found on the returned component instance: you may have forgotten to define `render`, returned null/false from a stateless component, or tried to render an element whose type is a function that isn't a React component.

Comment: I don't think the issue comes from the function itself but the way you're using it. We need more code.

Comment: I edited it to add more info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now you can return an array , try out the React 16 Beta

Comment: As stated by @Cristian that is now possible. https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html#new-render-return-types-fragments-and-strings

Comment: So that means I cant return multiple tags but I can return an array of tags?

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue rely on the inability for stateless functions to handle anything else than a single JSX element. It simply doesn't know how to render properly your array.

I would advice you to wrap your array elements in a root `<div>` like this to make it work:

```
function DeliveryPreference (props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h4>Delivery Preference</h4>
      <div className='yesNoCheckbox'>
        <input type="radio" value={'tube'} onChange={props.onChange} id='tube' checked={props.value === 'tube'}/> <label htmlFor='tube'>Tube</label> <br/>
        <input type="radio" value={'plate'} onChange={props.onChange} id='plate' checked={props.value === 'plate'}/> <label htmlFor='plate'>Plate</label><br/>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Or else decompose your two JSX elements in different functions.

Comment: Should anyone care for more detail, here's a link to the docs where it says that that `render` methods must always return [a single element](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#render), and from the blog where is says that stateless components are [just components with only a `render` method](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#stateless-functional-components).

Comment: Thanks for the links @JoshDavidMiller!